# Sound distortion when extracting from Jar

Tags: java, file

I have sounds in my jar file directory.
I need to use these sounds and I am trying to extract them using this method:

```
String charset = "ISO-8859-1";
public void extractSounds(String pathIn, String pathOut) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(pathIn), charset));
    String line = r.readLine();
    String result = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pathOut);
    while(line != null) {
        if(result != null) {
            result += "\r" + line;
            line = r.readLine();
        } else {
            result = line;
            line = r.readLine();
        }
    }
    fos.write(result.getBytes(charset));
}}
```

But when I extract the sounds they get distorted and I don't know what the problem is, because it basically just copies the file.
Sounds:
[Original](https://anonfiles.com/T7261dEfw3/9_wav),
[Extracted](https://anonfiles.com/v4b82fE0w6/9_wav)

I would be very grateful if you could help me find a solution or suggest another method to extract the sound files.

Comment: You treat binary data as text! You assume that it is broken up by newlines, which only makes sense for text. Try reading and writing the data as buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't assume you are reading text. You should not try to mutate the data. Just copy it in chunks.

Try something like

```
InputStream in = ...;
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final int BUF_SIZE = 1 << 8;
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
int bytesRead = -1;
while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: I tried your method, but it didn't work. It gives the same result as my code. Maybe I should use another write method instead of FileInputStream?

Comment: Thanks, I should have just used DataOutputStream.